# Can anyone help me identify this font type, style and size?

Tags: font-identification

I need to change this text to (Reference Details:) in same font style and size.
But i cant able to find the font style.I'm using adobe Photoshop cs 4. Can anyone help me?

[image: Table header]

[Full size sample here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx91A.gif).

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GD. Your sample is probably a bit too small to find the exact match. Is this actually text in a Photoshop file? Or is the source from somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Vnovak may be right, Arial, Bold, but your sample is a bit too small to tell.

[image: font comparison image]

The top line is Arial, Bold, created in Photoshop, the bottom line is your gif image, scaled up.